# PHP echo break tag

Tags: php, android

In my PHP script, there are 3 echo, based on the conditionals

```
echo "Error"
echo "User already existed"
echo "Success"
```

One of the echo will be passed to my android apps, `if (s.equals("Success"))`, where `s` is the echo message.

But the echo I got when the registration success is `<br />`, according to the logcat. For `User already existed` have no problem.

Since `s` is not `Success`, I can't start another activity which is depended on the string. Can anyone explain how the break tag got echoed? The registration information successfully inserted into database, though.

```
elseif ($roleID == "C") {
    $sql6 = "SELECT runnerID FROM tr_customer WHERE customerID = '$newID'";
    $check4 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql6));
    if(!isset($check4)) {
        // add into db
        $customerID = $roleID . $newID;
        $sql7 = "INSERT INTO tr_customer(customerID, name, phoneNo, locationID, roleID, email) VALUES ('$customerID', '$name', '$phoneNo', '$locationID', '$roleID', '$email')";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql7)) {
            echo "Success";
        }
    } else {
        $newID = checkExist();
}
```

Comment: Well, how should we answer without you posting the actual code? And by that I do not mean three incomplete lines out of context.

Comment: the actual code is too long but okay, I'll add which I think it's relevant

Comment: Sure, obviously only the relevant sections of the code.

Comment: @arkascha added the code

Comment: Not relevant for the question at hand... but if this code is fed by data submitted from the client side, then you are in high risk of sql injection attacks... Why not take advantage prepared statements and parameter binding as it is advertised wherever you look?

Comment: @arkascha yes I'm aware of it but for now I'll just go with it and will revise the code later

Comment: Changing code later always is _much_ more effort (and will usually _not_ get done) compare to doing things the right way right away. Using prepared statements is not more effort. Do it _now_.

Comment: I suspect that your php code sends an empty line, probably before that string`Success`. And that such an empty line is converted to a line break by some layer on the android side. Such empty lines are often the result of using php closing tags... But as said, that is only a _guess_. We cannot say anything by that little information given.

Answer (score -1):

I would examine the code where the variable is defined.  If you could post that part of the code as an edit then perhaps someone can review it for you as well.  There is just not enough information here to discern where your error is coming from.

EDIT:

Consider changing the way you check for a successful update.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql7);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
       echo "Success";
    }
```

Comment: Consider changing the way you check for a successful update.  I will edit my answer to show an example.

Comment: This is _not_ an answer to the question!

Comment: Well now it is, and I can't comment.  So how would you prefer I communicate that to him in the future?

Comment: @MattB. the result still the same. `<br />` printed.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` for an `INSERT` statement, but _never_ a result object.

Comment: @MattB. Consider that there are good reasons why people just starting at SO are blocked from commenting. It simply makes sense to look around first and only reply in cases where you are really absolutely certain what the answer to a question is.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are referring to when you mention a result object.  Does TRUE not evaluate as 1 when using "=="?  If it returns true or false and you check for == to 1 or 0 that should evaluate properly.

Comment: @MattB. You are trying to call `mysqli_num_rows(TRUE)` which will not work.

Comment: @arkascha, fair point..  I thought it was a select and not an insert, guess I read the code too fast.  Thanks.